# Finding most common values from a count in pandas jupyterbnote book

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I currently have a massive dataset with a large amount of rows and I wanted to create a smaller dataframe that only pulls 2 columns from the larger one and how many times each name occurred in that chapter in this instance 'Occurrence'

The below code is what I am using

```
 df1 = (Dec16.groupby(["BNF Chapter", "Name"]).size().reset_index(name="Occurrence"))
df1
```

It plots this

```
BNF Chapter       Name                                       Occurrence 
1                 Aluminium hydroxide                           2
1                 Aluminium hydroxide + Magnesium trisilicate   2
1                 Alverine                                      702
.......
21              Polihexanide                                     2
21              Potassium hydroxide                              32
21              Sesame oil                                       22
21              Sodium chloride                                  222
```

What I would like to get is the top 10 most occurred names for a certain chapter  as the dataset is so large.

For example a dataframe that only pulls 
The top 10 most common names in chapter 1

How would I go about doing this?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide more details like the structure of the dataframe, desired output, etc.

Comment: Please elaborate what you have tried yourself, what came out, and what you expected to come out.

Comment: @Peter smit I hope the above edit helps!

Comment: @NarenMurali Hi Naren, I have updated/edited my question - i hope this helps you to understand it a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [pandas.DataFrame.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)

This [Count Values In Pandas Dataframe](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_count_values.html) here can help you out I hope